# Conditional printing and counting over std::map with restrictions

Tags: c++, c++17, predicate, stdmap, std

I am currently in the process of learning C++17 and we were given a challenge as part of practicing using the Standard library to get used to using the features:

1. Iterate over a `std::map<std::string, size_t>` (also known as `std::map<file_name, file_size>`)
2. Print file names that are empty `size_t == 0` and return its count
3. Print file names that are not empty `size_t != 0` and return its count
4. Removing from map `std::pairs` `whose size_t == 0`

Restrictions:

1. Can only use headers: `<vector>`, `<map>`, `<string>`, `<algorithm>`, `<functional>`
2. Cannot define complex types nor templates
3. Cannot use the `. (member access), -> (member access via pointer), * (dereference) operators`
4. Cannot use `for, while, do-while nor if-else, switch` and other conditionals
5. Can use `std::for_each` and other functions of function templates to iterate over collection of elements
6. No lambdas
7. No `std::cout`, `std::cerr`, `std::ostream` etc.
8. No auto types
9. Can use other functions so long as they are included in the headers described at restriction #1

Allowed to use these functions:

```
void print(const std::string& str)
{
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

```
std::string split(const std::pair<std::string, size_t> &r)
{
    std::string name;
    std::tie(name, std::ignore) = r;
    return name;
}
```

```
bool checkEmpty(const std::pair<std::string, size_t>& r, bool trueIfIsNot
)
{
    file_size size;
    std::tie(std::ignore, size) = r;
    bool result = (size == 0);
    if (trueIfIsNot)
    {
        result = !result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

I have began to appreciate the use of `std::bind` and `std::for_each` in my previous post. This time, how do i add predicates and conditionals to modify the output without using syntax stated by restriction #4?

I am currently considering using `std::transform()` or maybe `std::copy_if()` etc. I have some understanding of many of the Standard Library's functions but i think i am very weak at the syntax to understand how things work together so i do not know how to make use of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 2,3 tasks you could do:

- use `vector` with initial size as map size
- use `copy_if` to copy elements from map depending on condition
- use `for_each` with bounded `split`/`print`
- return number of items as difference between first and last item in vector

The code:

```
int task2and3(const std::map<std::string,int>& m, bool trueIfIsNot)
{
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string,int>> vec(m.size());
    auto firstPastEnd = std::copy_if(m.begin(),m.end(),vec.begin(),
        std::bind(checkEmpty,std::placeholders::_1,trueIfIsNot));

    std::for_each(vec.begin(), firstPastEnd, 
        std::bind(print,std::bind(split,std::placeholders::_1)));

    return firstPastEnd - vec.begin();
}
```

by `trueIfIsNot` you indicate which pairs are printed (with value as 0 or otherwise).

---

To do 4-th task, you could also use `vector` to store items of `map`. To remove elements from map you could iterate over these items in vector (using `for_each`) and call `map::erase` method. Because this function member has overloads, you need to cast it properly to indicate method removing elements by `key_type`. Use `split` to get this `key_type` from pair.

```
void task4(std::map<std::string,int>& m)
{
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string,int>> vec(m.size());
    auto firstPastEnd = std::copy_if(m.begin(),m.end(),vec.begin(),std::bind(checkEmpty,std::placeholders::_1,false));

    using sizeType = std::map<std::string,int>::size_type;
    using keyType = std::map<std::string,int>::key_type;

    for_each(vec.begin(), firstPastEnd, 
        std::bind( static_cast<sizeType (std::map<std::string,int>::*)(const keyType&) >(&std::map<std::string,int>::erase),
        &m,
        std::bind(split,std::placeholders::_1)) );
}
```

[Full demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5cEkXD)